# Can't figure out how to solve this circular import

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I was splitting some functions into a separate file. Found the functions and helper functions. Set all the paths and import in other files so everything can still be called where necessary. But after removing an unused import from the original file it gives a circular import error it seems.

So there is an unused import and while there, every test (524) succeeds, but the branch cant be pushed because of the unused import. If we remove the import, the tests goes into circular import I think and wont start at all.

The first thing i tried is to change the regarding import statements from: from /module import /object  --> import module

This made the tests start but everything went wrong after that.

After that I tried to find a way through the circular import path but I just lost track of everything while I dont know if it is even a solution.

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 2, in <module>
    from x.model import x
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 1, in <module>
    import A
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 4, in <module>
    import B
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 1, in <module>
    import C
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 9, in <module>
    import D
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 4, in <module>
    import E
    File "/home/user/../.py", line 9, in <module>
    from x.model import x
ImportError: cannot import name 'x'
`
```

Comment: It is hard to help you because there is no code whatsoever in your question.

Comment: Also if you change it to `import module` you would probably need to append `module.object` instead of using directly the `object`. You could also work around that by trying to organise that module and using the `__init__` file so that it is easy to import it's content and users don't fall into circular imports

Comment: If you don't need object, why do you import module at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using imported `Ive` in `/home/user/projects/.../nsx/utils.py` file, inside some method or function, then you should remove import statement (i.e `from ive.models import Ive`) from top of file import statements(if you are doing so), and import it dynamically means put import statement at the place where you are using `Ive` inside the method or function.

```py
# Assume `/home/user/projects/.../nsx/utils.py` file

# Don't import Ive here
# from ive.models import Ive

def func():
     # import here
    from ive.models import Ive
    # use Ive here
```